# Getting individual page size of pdf in java

Tags: java, pdf, merge, pdfbox

My requirement is to split a pdf into certain fixed size chunks using java. I am using apache PDFBox for pdf operations. However I cant find any ready api method to get current page size in bytes. I need this information because only when I know what size of current page is, that I can keep adding pages upto the pre determined fixed size and then split into a new PDF till that point.

Comment: As of now, I have gotten through by writing individual page to the disk, then reading it as a whole file, getting the length and then deleting it. Granted that its a tad expensive due to IO but cant seem to find anything else on it.

Comment: The main problems are that **A** the size of a page is hard to calculate: On the one hand a page may require a large web of PDF objects used in concert, and on the other hand the size of these objects may vary substantially depending on the compression used; particularly if compressed object streams are used, the size of the compressed objects of one page depends on which objects have been compressed into the stream before. **B** The size of two pages may be considerably less than the sum of the sizes of each of them because the two pages may share a huge amount of resources.

Comment: Yup ! Just read about the whole pdf structure. Quite interesting. So of what I understand, the common object, say for example, headers and footers, are shared between pages and therefore there is only a single copy of such objects. If i were to split a 2page pdf into individual pdfs, then the resulting size would be more than the original pdf due to each of them now having their own copy of common objects.